# Is it possible to associate different kinds of custom post types one to the other?

Tags: custom-post-types, theme-development

I might be thinking too hard about this problem and i'm thinking the solution might be easier than we're i'm heading.

Here's what i'm trying to accomplish: there a winery website built on wp and uses custom post types for "Wines" -> every wine has it's own description, picture, etc (cabarnet 2005, cabarnet 2006 etc...). Now, most wines have won medals - some of them even won up to 8 medals. i want to showcase all medal relevant to a specific wine in his specific page AND i want to have another page that showcases all medals, chronologically.

I figured i might be able to accomplish this by creating a custom post type "medal" and to somehow associate the medal to the wine that won it. but can i associate the 'medal' object in a many to one relation to the 'wine' object? how can i do that?

Any Ideas?

Comment: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/posts-to-posts/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look at this plugin: [Custom Post Types Relationships (CPTR)](http://www.cssigniter.com/ignite/custom-post-types-relationships/). It lets you create relationships between posts, pages and custom posts types.

There is also the [Zig connect plugin](http://www.zigpress.com/plugins/zigconnect/) that has a very nice feature of reciprocity (no need to edit the second post, it will automatically be related to the first one).

Hope it helps.